# How to use rxjs 5.5.2 imports

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs

I don't understand how to RXjs operators should be imported.

Take a look at this simple code.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounce';

ngOnInit() {
    const temp_observable = this.store.select(state => state.accounts.pendingRequests)
      .filter(x => !!x)
      .map(x => x +1 )
      .debounce(x => Observable.timer(300));
}
```

But I keep getting:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.store.select(...).filter(...).map(...).debounce is not a function
```

The same thing happens when I use the import:

```
import {map, filter, debounce} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

But, If I change my code to use the Observable.of, it works-

```
const temp_observable = Observable.of(this.store.select(state => state.accounts.pendingRequests))
```

Is there a simpler way to solve this?
Can I import the common operators in the main.ts and not worry about it for each .ts file?

rxjs 5.5.2
angular 5.0.3
angular-redux 6.0.1
node 8.9.1

Answer (score 3):

The usage recommendations have changed somewhat since the introduction of the pipeable (previously lettable) operators. Try this code snippet -

```
import { debounce, filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

ngOnInit() {
  const temp_observable = this
    .store.select(state => state.accounts.pendingRequests)
    .pipe(
      filter(x => !!x),
      map(x => x +1 ),
      debounce(x => Observable.timer(300))
    );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: They are pipeable now:) https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md